# Create a field in form for each model instance related to another instance in django

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to write an exam system using django. I have two models. Exam, Question.

Now I want to create form in which user will be able to answer the questions. So I want a field for every question. how can I create such a form?

**UPD**: Below is my code for Exam and Question models

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django_jalali.db import models as jmodels
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from users.models import Member

# Create your models here.


class Exam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name=_("Exam's name"))
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(_("Start Date"))
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(_("End Date"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Exam")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Exams")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def stage(self):
        #raise ValueError("%d", self.end_date, datetime.now())
        if timezone.now() < self.start_date:
            return -1  # exam hasn't started yet
        elif timezone.now() >= self.end_date:
            return 1  # exam has ended
        else:
            return 0  # exam is running


class Question(models.Model):
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam, verbose_name=_("Related exam"))
    order = models.IntegerField(unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_("Question's index"),
                                help_text=_("Questions will be shown based on their index. Also this index is shown as the question's number in exam page"))
    statement = models.CharField(max_length=10000, verbose_name=_("Question's Statement"))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.exam.name + " - " + _("Question #") + str(self.order)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Question")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Questions")
        ordering = ['order']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a formset.

- [Formsets documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/)
- [Creating formsets from models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)

Ok, I'll explain.  First you should create Form with `question` (hidden) and `answer` (text) fields.

```
class AnswerForm(forms.Form):

    question = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Question.objects.all(),
                                      widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    answer = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

Next create formset with number of forms equal to the number of questions in exam.  For each form initial `question` will be concrete exam's `Question` instance.  Handling of the formset is standard as described in the documentation.

```
def pass_exam(request, exam_id):
    exam = get_object_or_404(Exam, pk=exam_id)
    questions = exam.question_set.all()
    num_questions = questions.count()
    AnswerFormSet = formset_factory(AnswerForm,
                                    max_num=num_questions, validate_max=True,
                                    min_num=num_questions, validate_min=True)
    initial = [{'question': q} for q in questions]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AnswerFormSet(request.POST, initial=initial)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                question = form.initial['question']
                answer = form.cleaned_data['answer']
                # SAVE THE ANSWER HERE
            return redirect('exam_done')
    else:
        formset = AnswerFormSet(initial=initial)
    return render(request, 'app/pass_exam.html',
                  {'exam': exam, 'formset': formset})
```

Ans last - create `pass_exam.html` template for this formset:

```
<h1>{{ exam }}</h1>

<form action="." method="POST">

    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {{ formset.non_form_errors }}

    {% for form in formset %}
        <p>
            {{ form.initial.question.statement }}<br />
            {{ form.question }}
            {{ form.answer }}
            {% if form.errors %}
                {{ form.answer.errors }}
                {{ form.question.errors }}
            {% endif %}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: I looked it up but could you give me an example? It is about creating a lot of forms for creating a model. What i want is different. I want to create a field for every question.

Comment: Show the code of your `Exam` and `Question` models, please.

Comment: I added them to my post.

Comment: Ok.  And where you suppose to save the answers?  Some sort of `Answer` model?

Comment: Yes, I have another Model which saves an answer for every question for each user. But I think it's ok if you'd assume I won't save the data.(for example I'll use them to process the score and show it to the user only). Does it change anything?

Comment: I added full example of plain (no Model) formset handling.