# django raising KeyError when accessing to field in self.initial

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

I've wrote a form called AnswerForm. This form is used to get an answer from the choices of the question.(Choice and Question are models). Here is my code to AnswerForm:

```
class AnswerForm(forms.Form):
    question = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Question.objects.all(),
                                      required=True,
                                      widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={"class": "hidden-input"}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['answer'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=self.initial["question"].choice_set.all(),
                                                       required=False,
                                                       widget=ExamChoiceInput)



    def clean_question(self):
        return self.initial["question"]
```

I use this form in a formset so user can answer many questions at one time. However when the users sends the form a KeyError value is raised for self.initial["question"] in second line of **init**. (I've printed self.initial and it's completely empty). Here is the function in which I process the request with post method:

```
def process_saving_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        current_user = request.user
        AnswerFormSet = formset_factory(AnswerForm)
        formset = AnswerFormSet(request.POST)

        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                new_user_madechoice = MadeChoice(
                            user=current_user,
                            choice=form.cleaned_data["answer"]
                        )
                try:
                    current_user_madechoice = current_user.madechoice_set.get(choice__question=form.cleaned_data["question"])
                    if current_user_madechoice.choice != form.cleaned_data["answer"]:
                        current_user_madechoice.delete()
                        new_user_madechoice.save()
                except MadeChoice.DoesNotExist:
                    new_user_madechoice.save()
```

May you tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did not pass any `initial` data to you `AnswerFormSet`.

See how I did it in the answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831594/create-a-field-in-form-for-each-model-instance-related-to-another-instance-in-dj/27831791):

```
initial = [{'question': q} for q in questions]
formset = AnswerFormSet(request.POST, initial=initial)
```

Comment: I'm very very thankful. I thought it isn't necessary and it will automatically get the questions using the posted form. Shouldn't it do it? since the id of the questions are sent inside the form as well?

Comment: To access question which is sent in the form you should use `cleaned_data["question"]` instead of `initial["question"]`. But I do not recommend it - user can alter the form and submit questions that not the same as in the `initial`.  BTW for the same reason you should  add `max_num`/`validate_max`/`min_num`/`validate_min` parameters to `formset_factory` constructor.

Comment: But wouldn't the problem be solved since I'm redefining clean_question in my from? I tried using self.cleaned_data in __init__(after posting the data) but it says there are no cleaned_data in self.

Comment: `cleaned_data` is not available in the form's `__init__` method.  It is populated later then you call `is_valid()` method which indirectly calls `full_clean()`.